# Charts will not resize with container

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, ng2-charts

I am using an ng2 Line Chart inside of a custom container to look like a mat-card. When the nav panel is hidden and displays the whole page the container resizes but the charts do not. If I put them on their own row they resize but next to each other they do not. For UI purposes I want to keep them side by side.

Before:

[image: Screenshot Before]

After:

[image: Screenshot After]

This is the code for the charts

```
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div style="display: block;">
            <canvas
                baseChart
                [datasets]="lineChartData"
                [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                [legend]="false"
                [colors]="lineChartColors"
                [chartType]="lineChartType"
            ></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the css for the container

```
.falseCard {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

html for the page it is on

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="16px">
        <div class="falseCard mat-elevation-z2"><ls-new-users-chart-widget></ls-new-users-chart-widget></div>
        <div class="falseCard mat-elevation-z2"><ls-active-users-chart-widget></ls-active-users-chart-widget></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some [configuration options for responsive charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html).

You'll definitely want to set `responsive` to true. Based on the images you provided, it seems you only want charts to resize horizontally so I will suggest that you set `maintainAspectRatio` to false.

1. Create the config object in your chart component class

   lineChartOptions: ChartOptions = { // dont forget to import the ChartOptions type from chart.js
   responsive: true,
   maintainAspectRatio: false
   }
2. Bind the config object to `options` of the `baseChart` in your template